# Unable to import installed python modules in Rmarkdown with reticulate

Tags: python, module, r-markdown, reticulate

I just installed the R package 'reticulate' and I found it especially useful. But with one con that I need to re-install python module (i.e. pandas) I have already installed.
The python engine is miniconda and the evnv is by default.
How can I specify the python interpreter so that I dont need to re-install all the installed module?
(After some search, I guess it has sth to do with 'virtualenv-tools ' in reticulate?)
By the way, I used to execute python with pycharm and the interpreter is system interpreter located in c://python//python.exe

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [this page](https://rstudio.github.io/reticulate/articles/r_markdown.html), you have to specify which Python engine you want, in this case miniconda, but just have to tell Rmarkdown where that is located on your computer using the `use_python` function.

````
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(reticulate)
use_python('/location/to/engine')
```
````

Comment: Yes, I have already looked related pages on reticulate. And I execute the following code in Rmd : 'use_python('C:\\python\\python.exe')' I still cant import module like 'torch.'  How could I find the path of my current python engine?